# Replace pandas iterrows() with apply & lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working code to add a new column to Pandas DataFrame using iterrows(). But it is extremely slow

```
df1['Kite_Token'] =0

for row,col in df.iterrows():
    df1.loc[row, 'Kite_Token'] = df_instrument[(df_instrument.exchange_token==col.SC_CODE) & (df_instrument.exchange == 'BSE')].instrument_token.to_string(index=False)
```

Here is my try to use apply and lambda to the above code but am getting the copy warning. Any faster way to accomplish without warning message?

```
df1['Kite_Token']= df1['SC_CODE'].apply(lambda x : df_instrument[(df_instrument.exchange_token==x) & (df_instrument.exchange == 'BSE')].instrument_token.to_string(index=False))

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Comment: You don’t need to use `iterrows` most likely. Are you just trying to add a new column if certain conditions are met?

Comment: Using `.apply` just hides a for loop.  You should try to use boolean slicing to set the values.

Comment: Yes, I'm  just trying to add a new column if certain conditions are met

Comment: you can use use `np.select(conditions, choices, default)`

Comment: Without seeing some of `df`, `df1`, and `df_instrument`, this is a very hard question to answer